# Google Apps Script: Get the ID of script bound to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to write a Google Apps Script to generate a list of the IDs of the scripts bound to certain spreadsheets.

I cannot find a way to programmatically, via GAS, get the ID of a bound script.

- If I have a [`spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object, I have methods like `getId` to get the ID of the spreadsheet, but not the bounded script.
- Using the DriveApp, I can find standalone scripts using `DriveApp.getFilesByType('application/vnd.google-apps.script')` but not bound ones!

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120078/gas-get-bounded-script-id-from-another-project https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184468/9337071 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117105104 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117105106 https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/208 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613469/how-to-programmatically-create-a-list-of-google-apps-script-projects-owned-by-me

Comment: And https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately (by my own research) this is not currently possible.  I have been wanting to programatically identify and access bound scripts for several years, I look into it periodically, I've always come up empty handed.

Haven't found any Google documentation explicitly on the topic, still hoping this hole gets filled eventually.

Comment: bound script files are "hidden" in Google Drive, they wont show up on search, although we can access/download them, after we know their Id