# How to rename copy of a bound script programatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I want to make a regular backup of a project ([default GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects)) that is coded on top of Google Spreadsheet. And on top of the it is a COPY of original SpreadSheet. So the project script file is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet.

`Bound scripts generally behave like standalone scripts except that they do not appear in Google Drive` a quote from above documentation link.

I guess that is the reason why I get an error

```
Error  GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 
     12OX6dRqsEHRsR4MttkDQ71yW_I8R2UqjfcSq4FB backupSS  @ web functions.gs:3958
```

on the 4th line of below code. Note that the scriptId exists but the file is not accessable

```
var spreadSheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()  
var scriptId = ScriptApp.getScriptId()
console.log(Drive.Files.get(spreadSheetId))
console.log(Drive.Files.get(scriptId))
```

with this result

```
9:24:12 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:24:12 PM  Info    PR-Digitalizace objednávek
9:24:12 PM  Error   GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.get failed with error: File not found: 12OX6dRPKwwt1-vOtCsbDEHRsR4MttkDQ71yW_I8R2Uqq4FB
backupSS    @ web functions.gs:3958

console.log(DriveApp.getFileById(scriptId).getName()) givess me this error `Error   
Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.
backupSS    @ web functions.gs:3959`
```

is there any way to edit scritp name programatically? Why so I do not have lots of script with the same name.

**Update**

- Google Apps Script API is **on**
- Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

  function getScriptContent(scriptId,content,theAccessTkn) {
  try{
  var options,payload,response,url;

  ```
    if (!scriptId) {
      scriptId = ScriptApp.getScriptId()
    }

    if (!content) {
      //Error handling function
      console.log("no content")
    }

    if (!theAccessTkn) {
      theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    }

    //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent
    url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId +"content"
    url = "https://scriptmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId //+"content"


    options = {
      "method" : "GET",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  theAccessTkn
      },
      "contentType": "application/json",//If the content type is set then you can stringify the payload
  //    "payload": JSON.stringify(content)
    };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);      
    console.log('getResponseCode ' + response.getResponseCode())
    console.log("Response content: " + response.getContentText())
    console.log("finished " )
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Error: " + e + "\nStack: " + e.stack)
  }
  ```

  };

gives me

```
    Response content: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try using the Apps Script API. It allows you to manage document bound scripts. See documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api

Comment: Are you renaming the 'Untitled project' or the 'Code.gs'?

Comment: @NaziA: the project got a name alredy. But I want to make a copy of the spreadsheet. In such case the project is cloned and then I end up with two projects with the same name. If I create back up every day then ....

Comment: @Radek, I see. I'm not sure why yours doesn't work as I don't get any errors whatsoever from the snippet above. Although if that still don't work, can you try `DriveApp.getFileById(scriptId).setName('Renamed project')` ? it works on my side. Just make sure to have it refreshed after running to see the change.

Comment: I will not work .. my script is bound. Create you script from a spreasheet and try.

Comment: If what you want is to automatically rename the project after duplicating the spreadsheet, i believe that is still impossible. There is currently no way to get the id of the script bound to a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54990478/google-apps-script-get-the-id-of-script-bound-to-a-spreadsheet

Comment: Hi @Radek, I've just confirmed that the code above i provided will work on original files and the script bound to it. BUT it will not work on copied files and its bound script.

Comment: there is no difference if the file/project is copied or not. The above code does not work for me even for the original spreadsheet/project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I can still access the original bound script via `DriveApp`

#### Code:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(scriptId).setName('tester');
```

#### Original:

[image: success]

But not when running it on the copied file

#### Copied file:

[image: error]

#### Conclusion:

- I haven't found any possible way to automatically rename the bound script after duplicating/copying it. Also there's currently no method that allows you to get the ids of the script bound to a file.
- And if the above code wouldn't work even on original for you, then that would make it even harder.

#### Resources:

- [Google Apps Script: Get the ID of script bound to a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991427/14606045)

Comment: is your script bound AND default GCP project ?

Comment: Yes to both @Radek. As you can see, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()` is returning an ID.

Comment: @Radek, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId() ` would result into `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of null` if this is stand alone script.

Comment: well, then it is not working for me because of something else ... I am using basically

Comment: console.log(DriveApp.getFileById(scriptId).getName()) givess me this error `Error 
Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.
backupSS @ web functions.gs:3959`

Comment: @Radek, most likely that file is already a copy of a different file. If you create a new sheet and use the code above in a new script bound to it, it should execute properly. Unfortunately, this approach would be useless in your case since you are creating multiple copies and the code above is proven unusable in those cases.

Comment: You are right. I can confirm that the issue is with a copy of the spreadsheet. The bound script then behaves strangely.

Comment: Feel free to file the issue as bug at issuetracker.google.com @Radek.